# When p is prime number, explain all the elements of $S_p$, whose the order is not divisible by any prime numbers less than p

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetric-groups

I'm studying a first course in abstract algebra, and currently I'm stuck with this problem.

The problem is that, when p is prime number, explain all the elements of $S_p$, whose the order is not divisible by any prime numbers less than p.

I just know that the group $S_p$ is generated by any transposition and any p-cycle.

Can you suggest possible approaches or ideas?

Comment: Hint: look at cycle decompositions

Comment: I'm sorry, can you explain a bit more about it?

Comment: Do you know what cycle decomposition is?

Comment: Yes, if the cycle decomposition of a is a = (1,5)(2,4)(3), then a consists of the product of 3 cycle.

Comment: I'm just wondering, in this problem, I think that the only candidate of order that is not divisible by any prime numbers less than p is p. So, I already know that in $S_p$, the only p cycle has the order p, which means the other cycle types can't have the order p. Thus, all the elements of $S_p$ is p cycle. Am I on wrong track?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, every element of $S_p$ is, for example, if $2< p$, $[2]=\{n \in \Bbb Z: n\mod(p) =2\}.$ All the numers of $[2]$ are viewed as the same element of $S_p$, i.e., $[2]$.

Comment: I don't understand: what do you think $\;S_p\;$ is? Because I think the OP means the symmetric group of order $\;p!\;$ and you seem to be referring to other thing.